# Pressing uibutton causes (lldb) error with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift4, presentviewcontroller

So my view controller is not presenting another view controller when the button is touched. Instead, on the last line of code I receive the error:

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).

The debug console also shows the message:
(lldb)

I am trying to navigate from my getStarted page to my signUp page.

I appreciate the help.

```
let getStartedButton: UIButton = {
let getStartedButton =  UIButton()

getStartedButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.24, green:0.51, blue:0.59, alpha:1.0)
getStartedButton.setTitle("Get Started", for: .normal)
getStartedButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 18)
getStartedButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
getStartedButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)

return getStartedButton


}()

@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
let destinationVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUpViewController") as! SignUpViewController
self.present(destinationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Is the custom class for the view controller with identifier `SignUpViewController` set to `SignUpViewController`?  Replace the force downcast with `if let destinationVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUpViewController") as? SignUpViewController {
self.present(destinationVC, animated: true, completion: nil) } else { print("Could not create VC") }` and see what happens

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the crash? What's the complete error message? And please fix your title. That's not the same error in your question.

Comment: Yes the custom class is set to the right viewcontroller. I tried your code and the debug console printed "Could not create VC"
@Paulw11

Comment: Set a breakpoint and work out what is going wrong; either `self.storyboard` is `nil` or `instantiateViewController` isn't returning an instance of `SignUpViewController`

Comment: I tried that. self.storyboard is not nil. It seems to be the issue of the instantiateViewController not returning an instance of SignUpViewController @Paulw11

Comment: Remove the forced downcast and then in the debugger you can see what `destinationVC` is; It could be some other class or it could be `nil` if the scene can't be found.

Comment: If what is meant by nil is presented by destinationVC = 0x0000000000000000 then yes that is shown. @Paulw11

Comment: The debug only presents the error (lldb) and, the last line of code is causing the problem: 
@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
let destinationVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUpViewController") as! SignUpViewController
self.present(destinationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
} -rmaddy

Comment: both get started and signup are both in same storyboard

Comment: No they are not. They are in different storyboards. @Vinodh

Comment: then give your storyboard name and storyboard id as follows let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someViewController")
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide the Storyboard name and storyboard id so that you will be able to navigate easily

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil) 
let destinationVC : SignUpViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUpViewController") 
self.present(destinationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check you assign custom class (SignUpViewController) to view controller in storyboard, also check did you assign identity storyboard ID 'SignUpViewController' properly(its case sensitive). like below : [image: Show how to assign custom class & identifier]